# Rpcbind error in Docker: cannot run multiple rpcbind services

Tags: docker, containers, nis

I run two containers on my host (e.g, A and B). On container A, the rpcbind service start normally. However, when I start rpcbind service on container B, there are errors listed below:

```
# service rpcbind restart
 * Stopping RPC port mapper daemon rpcbind                                                                                                                                                             [ OK ]
 * Starting RPC port mapper daemon rpcbind                                                                                                                                                                    rpcbind: another rpcbind is already running. Aborting
```

Then I stop the rpcbind service on container A, the rpcbind service can be started normally on container B.

By the way, the rpcbind service on host is running normally. It seems that there is only one rpcbind service allowed to run in docker.

The host system is CentOS 7, and the docker container's based image is ubuntu/20.04. My initial aim is set the containers A and B as NIS client by the script below:

```
service rpcbind start
service nis start
```

Since there is only one normal rpcbind service, I cannot start containers A and B simultaneously.

Any solution or suggestion? Thanks.

I have tried to change the docker network to solve this issue, but it does not work.

I expect to start nis client normally on multiple containers simultaneously.

Comment: The `service` command doesn't usually work in Docker at all, and you shouldn't normally need to manually start things inside a container (the container's single main process should just run the program in the foreground).  As you've described this it doesn't really seem like a programming-related question at all.  Do you have a [mcve] showing what's in the Dockerfile(s)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, the confusing thing is that the ```service``` command can only work in one container (A or B). So, how can I start nis client service for multiple containers?